# Login to main app

Tags: iphone, ios, authentication, modalviewcontroller

I've already built the main app and the login.

In the **appDelegate.m didFinishLaunchingWithOptions**, I have

```
[self.window addSubview:rootController.view];
```

Which loads up the mainView.

However, I would want it to load up my login first as on a successful login, it will load the rootController (main app) etc.

When I put

```
[self.validateViewController presentModalViewController:validateViewController animated:YES];
```

and run the app, all I get is a white screen.

What am I doing wrong?

-> The reason I'm trying to do this is because at the moment, I have the rootController load up first but in the viewDidLoad, it loads the Login modal. Because of that, it runs numberOfRowsInSection first and so when I do eventually go into the app after login, it won't show any tableview since it's already gone through numberOfRowsInSection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to run `presentModalViewController` on a controller that has a view being displayed already. Right now you are running `presentModalViewController` on the view you actually want to present.

You could present the validateViewController after adding the rootController to the app window:

```
[rootViewController presentModalViewController:validateViewController animated:YES];
```

Comment: I get an error saying Thread 1: Program received signal. "SIGABRT".

Comment: Am I suppose to do an IBOutlet ValidateViewController *validateViewController in the appDelegate.h and @property it. Then #import ValidateViewController.h, @synthesize validateViewController and release it? I am doing that but get the "SIGABRT" message when I run it... Thanks in advance.

Comment: From your question, I got the impression that you were already instantiating the validateViewController within your app-delegate's didFinishLaunchingWithOptions?! There is no need to create a property if you do not plan to access that viewController from outside of your app-delegate. Just create a local instance, present it and release it again right away. The rest will be taken care of automagically.

Comment: Hi Till, thank you for your help so far. I'm still having trouble though. :(. At the moment, it looks like this: img683.imageshack.us/i/unlediem.png and img691.imageshack.us/i/unled1hl.png Please could you help. Thanks.

Comment: @K.Hoda Sorry but that is now very much tending into the "Gimme teh codez" direction. Please do not be offended but you should really learn a little more about ObjectiveC and CocoaTouch. Maybe read a book or run through some tutorials.

Comment: Can you tell me if this is the best way to approach this? At the moment, I have the Login page load up from my mainApps' viewDidLoad. Therefore it's running numberOfRowsInSection on the mainApp before the login so it will not populate the tableview. All the Json stuff is in viewWillAppear. Is there a way to run numberOfRowsInSection in the mainApp after the Login? Thanks.

Comment: reloadData in viewWillAppear?

Comment: reloadData whereever your data has changed but your view still contains the old data (or no data at all).

Comment: No Data at all since it does not run numberOfRowsInSection. Do I have to do it on the Login Page?

Answer (score 1):

Just present the login by

```
[self presentModalViewController:validateViewController animated:YES];
```

Comment: An error comes up saying: Use of undeclared identifier 'validateViewController'... Any more suggestions? Thanks.

Comment: you need to have an instance of validateViewController. Initialize it first

Comment: Please can you show me? I'm really stuck. At the moment, I have IBOutlet ValidateViewController *validateViewController in the appDelegate.h and @property it. Then #import ValidateViewController.h, @synthesize validateViewController and released it. Thanks.

Comment: Allocate validateViewController before u present it

Comment: 'ValidateViewController *validateViewController = [[ValidateViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ValidateViewController" bundle:nil];'
    'validateViewController.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationFullScreen;'
    '[self presentModalViewController:validateViewController animated:YES];'
    '[validateViewController release]; This throws the error "SIGABRT"' :(.

Comment: terminate called after throwing an instance of 'NSException'. It looks like this at the moment... img683.imageshack.us/i/unlediem.png and img691.imageshack.us/i/unled1hl.png