# reloadData after Login on iPhone app

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview, authentication, reloaddata

I have a **Login** that is initiated on the **viewDidLoad** of the mainApp. This means **numberOfRowsInSection** in the mainApp runs before the **Login** and results my **tableview** not being populated.

I have my **JsonArray** in the **viewWillAppear** in the mainApp the reloadData function to make **numberOfRowsInSection** run after the **Login** as well. So I put:

```
    [self.tableView reloadData];
```

...in the viewWillAppear. But this doesn't make it run after Login.

Any suggestions?

Thanks in advance.

**CODE UPDATE**

**Login Page**

```
    if (serverOutput != nil) {
    //UIAlertView *alertSuccess = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Congrats" message:@"You are authorised" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
    //[alertSuccess show];
    //[alertSuccess release];

    LucentaAppDelegate *appDelegate = (LucentaAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
    appDelegate.userProducts = serverOutput;

    loginButton.enabled = FALSE;

    [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

**Main View**

```
    - (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
[super viewWillAppear:animated];

LucentaAppDelegate *appDelegate = (LucentaAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
self.jsonArray = [appDelegate.userProducts JSONValue];

//[self.tableView reloadData];
[self performSelector:(@selector(refreshDisplay:)) withObject:(tableView) afterDelay:0.5];

UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"Test Alert" message:@"View Will Appear." delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel" otherButtonTitles: nil];
[alert show];
[alert release]; }

    -(void)refreshDisplay:(UITableView *)tableView {
[self.tableView reloadData];}
```

Comment: How do you know when your login process is completed? Is there a callback or a delegate method? If so, put your reload command there.

Comment: When the login process is complete, the login modalviewcontroller will disappear and show the mainView.

Comment: Looks a lot like your old, expanded question; [login-to-main-app](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6122242/login-to-main-app)!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When your login (started in `viewWillLoad`) is completed, you should get some delegate callback call that tells you that your request as completed. You usually specify the `delegate` when creating the request.

If you are using NSURLRequest and `NSURLConnection`, the delegate is specified in one of:

```
+ connectionWithRequest:delegate:
– initWithRequest:delegate:
– initWithRequest:delegate:startImmediately:
```

depending on how your create the request, and the delegate callback to override is `connectionDidFinishLoading:` (or `connection:didFailWithError:` in case of communication errors).

`connectionDidFinishLoading:` is the right place where you should issue your `[self.tableView reloadData];`, after having updated your table data source.

If you are not using `NSURLRequest`, then the delegate callback will be different.

EDIT:

if your `mainView` receive the JSon data it needs, what you should do there is update your table data source and call `reloadData` on the table.

Indeed, calling `reloadData` will force calling `numberOfRowsInSection` again, but this information is provided by your data source, so if it is not updated to reflect the new data you have received, it will always reflect the old value.

Could you provide more information about your data source?

Comment: Sergio, upon a successful login. It is dismissing the Login modal and sending a JSON array to the mainView to populate the tableview. However, because the numberOfRowsInSection in the mainView has run before the Login page, I would like to reloadData in order to populate the tableView in the mainView.

Comment: Hey sergio... It seems like I have figured it out. If there are any problems, I'll let you know. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

That depends on the actual code of your app. I suggest just to put a method like

```
- (void)loginSucceeded {
    [self.tableView reloadData];
}
```

to your view controller and call it after the login was successful. It is also convenient as you might need to do some more complicated actions in this situation when your app grows.

Comment: Am I suppose to do that in my Login Page as I did that in the mainView? So I should call that after a successful login in the Login page?

Comment: Call it whenever your data is ready to be presented in your table view. Yes, after a successful login before presenting your main view.

Comment: Cool... How can I reference the tableview in my mainView in the Login page in order to make the tableview reloadData? Thanks.